# Group dates by week during multiple years

Tags: c#, list, date, datetime

I have a list of `DateTime` values and I want to split the whole list into sublists for each week.

The dates might span across multiple years(the user selects the start and end date), so a solution that splits them up per calendar week number would end up in conflicts.

Is there a way to traverse the list and then store each week's `DateTime` values in a new 2d list?

The values available are from Monday to Friday and first and last week might have fewer values.

The only relevant question I found is [How to group dates by weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561782/how-to-group-dates-by-week?rq=1) but it is not suitable for my case.

Comment: something like this except grouping by the year and week number: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363655/c-sharp-list-groupby-2-values ?

Comment: If you multiple the year by 100 and then added the week it would give a unique grouping.  then you would have to handle the case were the week spanned over two years.  So you would test for week 1 and if it started on Sunday then include in current year, otherwise, subtract one from the year and add 53.

Comment: would also work although it hides the meaning a bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11155102/284240) to get the week-number of a given `DateTime`. Then you can use `Enumerable.GroupBy` with an anonymous type containing the year and the weeknum:

```
var yearWeekGroups = allDates.GroupBy(d => new { d.Year, WeekNum = GetIso8601WeekOfYear(d) });
```

If you want a `List<List<DateTime>>` where each sub-list contains the dates of a week:

```
List<List<DateTime>> allWeeks = yearWeekGroups.Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
```

---

If your country doesn't use ISO 8601 you can use [`Calendar.GetWeekOfYear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var cc = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var yearWeekGroups = allDates.GroupBy(d => new 
{ 
    d.Year, 
    WeekNum = currentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(d, cc.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, cc.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek) 
});
```