# Group the DataTable by weeks

Tags: c#, linq

I want to group my `DataTable` by weeks and display it to the `DataGridView`.

Here is my code:

```
var week = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"]))
              .Select(g => new
              {
                  Date = g.Key.ToString(),
              }).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = week;
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Do you want to convert the dates into weekly buckets? Like "1W", "2W", "3W" and so on?

Comment: my question sir @S.Akbari is how to group it by week?

Comment: Yes sir @Skyuppercut

Comment: refer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561782/how-to-group-dates-by-week and change the logic to handle datatable

Comment: Which date belongs to which week, do you already have that data or do you plan to add it by code. Once you have Week wise division, then it would be a breeze to group by week

Comment: I have already the data and it is in days, so i need to group it by week

Comment: And when you say "by week", do you mean by ISO Standard Week Number, other Week number, every seven days, etc. ? Do you want to count the [first full week](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendarweekrule?view=netframework-4.7) or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `System.Globalization` namespace to find the week of year for a `DateTime`, using the rules you would like:

```
using System.Globalization;

DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;

var week = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => 
                  dfi.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"]), dfi.CalendarWeekRule, 
                                             dfi.FirstDayOfWeek))
              .Select(g => new
              {
                  Date = g.First()["Date"].ToString(),
              }).ToList();
```

I couldn't figure out how your `Select` related to grouping by weeks without more information, so I just chose the first Date of each group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
 private static string[] TimeBucket = { "0D", "1D", "1W", "2W", "1M", "2M", "3M", "6M", "9M", "1Y", "2Y", "3Y", "5Y", "10Y", "15Y", "20Y", "25Y", ">=30Y" };

        private static int[] TimeIntervals = { 0, 1, 7, 2 * 7, 30, 2 * 30, 3 * 30, 6 * 30, 9 * 30, 365, 2 * 365, 3 * 365, 5 * 365, 3650, 15 * 365, 20 * 365, 25 * 365, 30 * 365 };


        private static string ComputeMaturity(DateTime? mat, DateTime? refDate)
        {
            if (!mat.HasValue)
                return "Void";

            int nbd = (mat - refDate).Value.Days;

            for (int pos = 0; pos < TimeBucket.Length; pos++)
                if (nbd < TimeIntervals[pos])
                    return TimeBucket[pos];
            return TimeBucket[(TimeBucket).Length - 1];
        }
```

During groupby,

```
var week = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => ComputeMaturity(Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"]),DateTime.Now))
              .Select(g => new
              {
                  Date = (g.Key),
              }).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = week;
```

Comment: You can define your own timebuckets using this answer and group your dates into those buckets

Comment: Thank you sir Skyuppercut ! i will try this

Comment: Sir @Skyuppercut, i tried it but my datatable didnt group.

Comment: It only shows the time buckets,not grouped . Please sir help me 

Comment: it will work now. I grouped by first and then converted to buckets. You should convert and then groupby.